# OSX Lion Bluetooth RSSI monitor

Tags: bash, bluetooth, osx-lion

I have written a simple bash script for Mac Yosemite that retrieves and appends the rssi value of a paired Bluetooth connection to a text file when a desktop icon is clicked.  It works ok.  Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
rs=`system_profiler SPBluetoothDataType | grep RSSI`
echo $rs ,$(date) >> Desktop/rssilog.txt;
exit;
```

My question is that I want to run this on an older MacMini that can't be updated past Lion, and the system_profiler in that version does not show the rssi level.  You can still get the rssi information from the Bluetooth menu, so I know the information is in there.  I just can't figure out how to get to it from the terminal command line.  Someone please tell me it's possible!

EDIT:: No response over the weekend.  Is there a better forum to post this question?